# A polynomial time algorithm for the Minimum ratio spanning tree problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider an undirected graph $G(V,E)$ with two real edge weights $w_e$ and $v_e$. Assume that $\sum_{e \in E_{T^*}} v_e >0$.
>
> Find a spanning tree $T^* = (V,E_{T^*})$ that minimises
>
> $$\frac{\sum_{e \in E_{T^*}} w_e}{\sum_{e \in E_{T^*}} v_e}$$
>
> in polynomial time.

I suppose we have to define a new weight function that combines $w_e$ with $v_e$ and to use the algorithms we already have for minimum spanning trees. But I do not see how I could do that. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bounds on the numerator and denominator to obtain bounds for the ratio.  Then apply bisection search on the resulting interval $[L,U]$ for the ratio.  To test whether there is a tree with ratio at most $r$, solve a minimum spanning tree problem with weights $w_e-r v_e$ and compare to 0.  There will be $O(\log_2 (U-L))$ MST calls.

Comment: Why do we compare to $0$? Do you mean $max\{w_e-rv_e, 0\}$ ?

Comment: $(\sum w_e)/(\sum v_e)\le r \iff \sum (w_e-r v_e) \le 0$

Comment: This approach assumes that $\sum v_e > 0$.